# Fixed Footer's position iTextPdf7 - Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a single page A4 pdf generated by itextpdf7, I want to fix the position of the footer(which is a SeparatorLine and two lines of Text) to be always at the bottom of the page.

Here is my Footer's Code :

```
 public void addFooter(Document layoutDocument) {

    SolidLine line = new SolidLine(1f);
    LineSeparator ls = new LineSeparator(line);
    ls.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    ls.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(70));
    Div div = new Div();
    div.add(ls);
    layoutDocument.add(div);
    Paragraph footerFirstParagraph = new Paragraph();
    footerFirstParagraph.add(new Text("ADRESSE : ").setBold());
    footerFirstParagraph.add(new Text("ADDRESSE HERE"));

    layoutDocument.add(footerFirstParagraph.setFont(pdfTextFont).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
            .setFontSize(10));

    Paragraph footerSecondParagraph = new Paragraph();
    footerSecondParagraph.add(new Text("3443443: ").setBold());
    footerSecondParagraph.add(new Text("3443443"));
    footerSecondParagraph.add(new Text("344").setBold());
    footerSecondParagraph.add(new Text("34434"));     
    footerSecondParagraph.add(new Text("3443443: ").setBold());
    footerSecondParagraph.add(new Text("3443443"));   
    footerSecondParagraph.add(new Text("3443443: ").setBold());
    footerSecondParagraph.add(new Text("3443443"));

    layoutDocument.add(footerSecondParagraph.setFont(pdfTextFont).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
            .setFontSize(10));      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after some trials.

```
Div div = new Div();
div.add(ls);
div.add(footerFirstParagraph);
div.add(footerSecondParagraph);
div.setFixedPosition(float positionFomleft(50), 
                     float positionFromBottom(30),
                     float widthOfDiv (UnitValue.createPercentValue(float val)));
layoutDocument.add(div);
```